# Get all products which have both product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need all products which have both categories. I am using a query below:

```
$args = array(
                            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms'    => array( 'shop', 'cat1' ),
                                    'operator' => 'AND',
                                )
                            )
                        );
```

It's working correctly if cat1 category does not have any subcategory like cat1-1,cat1-2 etc. But when i made subcategory in backend of cat1 than result will give zero.

Query is same just no result if cat1 have subcategory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add include children in your arguments.

Make sure your products have both categories.

In case you want to filter by multiple categories operator could be 'IN' instead of 'AND'.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
'paged' => $paged,
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'include_children' => true,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'shop', 'cat1' ),
            'operator' => 'AND',
        )
    )
);
```